# Rendering button with CAGradientLayer

Tags: swift, xcode, button

when I set a button with the CAGradientLayer it is not displayed correctly.

```
func setGradientBackground(color_A: UIColor, color_B: UIColor, indexLayer : Int){

    let granderLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    granderLayer.frame = bounds
    granderLayer.colors = [color_A.cgColor, color_B.cgColor]
    granderLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
    granderLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    granderLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)

    layer.insertSublayer(granderLayer, at: UInt32(indexLayer))
}
```

[image]

[image]

in the case of a UITableView after a scroll this works

Answer (score 0):

You should check the value of bounds in this line: "granderLayer.frame = bounds".